# Calculate location on line with known azimuth to point

Tags: geometry, algorithm, mathematics

I have the following situation (consider distances up to 300m - without great circle etc. affects):

[image]

How can I calculate the unknown location when I have all other locations in the triangle and azimuth to the unknown location from some source point (green)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uploaded some photos which include a solution. Have a look at it.

[image]

[image]

[image]